# Minimizing a two variables function in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and I'm looking for tutorials minimizing an equation
I tried to implement an example for minimizing a function:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(random.randn, name='x')
y= tf.Variable(random.randn, name='y')

fx = 2*x -3*y

opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(fx)

with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
   for i in range(5):
     print(sess.run([x,y]))
     sess.run(opt)
```

Works very good.

But how can I do it for this type of equation as an example:

e^x+ xy = 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to minimize the l2 loss, i.e:

```
fx = tf.nn.l2_loss(tf.exp(x)+tf.multiply(x,y)-20)
```

There are other possibilities of course, but this is an example.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.